# $|x|^mu \to 0, \forall m>0 \text{ as } |x| \to \infty$ $\implies$ $v(x) = ⨍_{\partial B(0,\vert x \vert)} u(t) \ dt$ has the same property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function. 
$\newcommand{\avint}{⨍}$

Suppose that $$|x|^mu \to 0 \quad \forall m>0, \text{ as } |x| \to \infty.$$

How can I prove that function 
$$v(x) = \avint_{\partial B(0,\vert x \vert)} u(t) \ dt \ $$ 
is also continuous and 
$$|x|^mv \to 0 \quad \forall m>0, \text{ as } |x| \to \infty?$$

Answer (score 1):

- To prove continuity, use the fact that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ s.t. $$\int_E |f|<\varepsilon,$$
  for all mesurable set $E$ s.t. $m(E)<\delta.$
- To prove that $|x|^mv\to 0$, remark that

$$v(x)=\frac{1}{|\partial B(0,|x|)|}\int_{\partial B(0,1)}r^{n-1}u(r\sigma )d\sigma,$$
and use $|x|^mu\to 0$ to bound usefully the integral.